# Add value of a dict to a variable

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that binds an integer to every character in the alphabet like so:

`letter_values = {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3}` and so on

My program asks the user for an input, iterates over each character of the string and adds the respecting value from the dictionary to a variable called score, like so:

```
word = raw_input('Please enter your word: ')
score = 0
if len(word) == 0:
    return score
else:
    for letter in word:
        for letter in SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES.keys():
            char_value = SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES.values()
            score += char_value
```

For the line in which I assign a value to the variable char_value, I get the following error:

```
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

By that I assume that Python doesn't recognize that the value in the dict is an integer (?) If so, how can I add the integers of the dict to the variable?

Comment: You're trying to add the whole of `.values()`, which is a list of *all values*, to an integer... Also, iterating over the dictionary like that makes absolutely no sense. Don't you just want `SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES[letter]`?

Comment: You are right with that, at the moment the code is not good. My problem is solved now, so I'm of to improve it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`values()` returns a list, not the specific value.  Dictionary values can be accessed by square brackets, though.  Try:

```
for letter in word:
    score += letter_values[letter]
```

Comment: Yep, Or `letter_values.get(letter,0)` if the OP is unsure that the element is present in the dictionary. [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict\[key\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11041405)